# Using javascript to make a random image/text/url element in html

Tags: javascript, html

Comments pretty much explain the stuff you can't see. randInt does exactly what you'd expect, adDescription generates a description of an ad based on the return of randInt, and rLink generates a link based on the same.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    rNumber = randInt(5); //generate a random integer from 1 to 5
    rAd = adDescription(rNumber); //description of the random ad
    rLink = adLink(rNumber); //URL of the random ad
    document.write("<a href='" + rLink + "'>");
    document.write("<img src='ad" + rNumber + ".jpg' alt='" + rAd "'/>");
    document.write("</a>");
</script>
```

My problem lies in my document.write calls.

When all is said and done, it should write the following to my html code

```
<a href="url">
    <img src="adn.jpg" alt="description"/>
</a>
```

Yes, this is for school, and I know exactly what I want to do, but for some reason it's not rendering, and in my head, this makes sense. What blatantly obvious mistake am I making that I just can't see?

Edit: Oh, and this script is being called in a predetermined part of pre-baked code that was given to me. The rest of my code worked properly prior to me inserting this code in the div element that I was instructed to. Additionally, I have called the scripts that contain the above functions in my document head.

Edit2: Yep, I feel dumb.

Comment: What do you mean by "not rendering", is nothing rendering at all?

Comment: Yes, it was not displaying anything at all. I've been given a solution, and as predicted, I feel really dumb after figuring out my problem :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a plus sign when you write out the `<img>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    rNumber = randInt(5); //generate a random integer from 1 to 5
    rAd = adDescription(rNumber); //description of the random ad
    rLink = adLink(rNumber); //URL of the random ad
    document.write("<a href='" + rLink + "'>");
    //                                                     Missed + here
    document.write("<img src='ad" + rNumber + ".jpg' alt='" + rAd + "'/>");
    document.write("</a>");
</script>
```

Comment: I knew it was just going to be some little stupid thing that I'm missing and can't see. That was definitely the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Having another set of eyes always helps haha
Glad I could help :)

Comment: The [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) in Chrome are great for finding issues. Press F12 on a page to open the tools. It takes time getting familiar with them but they'll save you tons of time.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `+` sign after `rAd` in the img src tag.

Here is the correct code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    rNumber = randInt(5); //generate a random integer from 1 to 5
    rAd = adDescription(rNumber); //description of the random ad
    rLink = adLink(rNumber); //URL of the random ad
    document.write("<a href='" + rLink + "'>");
    document.write("<img src='ad" + rNumber + ".jpg' alt='" + rAd + "'/>");
    document.write("</a>");
</script>
```